# Vite's createHtmlPlugin doesn't output html file

Tags: webpack, ejs, vite

I'm transitioning a project from webpack to vite, and part of the process is replacing the htmlwebpack plugin that was responsible for rendering a .liquid file based off of an html file with ejs templating. The previous code looked like this:

Here's what the directory looks like

```
.
├── .config/
│   └── webpack.dev.js
├── lib/
│   └── script-tags.html
├── dist/
│   └── snippets
└── vite.config.js
```

Here's how it was coded inside webpack.dev.js

```
...
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      excludeChunks: ['static'],
      filename: `${settings.theme.dist.snippets}/script-tags.liquid`,
      template: './lib/script-tags.html',
      inject: false,
      liquidTemplates: getTemplateEntrypoints(settings),
      liquidLayouts: getLayoutEntrypoints(settings),
    }),
...
```

And here is the code in vite.config.js

```
import path from 'path';
import { rootCertificates } from 'tls';

import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { createHtmlPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-html';

const settings = require('./lib/config').init();
const getLayoutEntrypoints = require('./lib/utilities/get-layout-entrypoints');
const getTemplateEntrypoints = require('./lib/utilities/get-template-entrypoints');

const baseConfig = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      'focus-trap-vue$': 'focus-trap-vue/dist/index.esm.js',
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, './scripts/components'),
      '@instances': path.resolve(__dirname, './scripts/instances'),
      '@libraries': path.resolve(__dirname, './scripts/libraries'),
      '@objects': path.resolve(__dirname, './scripts/objects'),
      '@partials': path.resolve(__dirname, './scripts/partials'),
      '@settings': path.resolve(__dirname, './scripts/settings'),
      '@utilities': path.resolve(__dirname, './scripts/utilities'),
      '@vendors': path.resolve(__dirname, './scripts/vendors'),
      '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, './styles'),
      '@modules': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
    },
    extensions: ['...', '.vue'],
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    import('vite-plugin-copy')
      .then((module) => module.copy([
        {
          src: settings.theme.src.assets,
          dest: settings.theme.roots.dist,
        },
        {
          src: settings.theme.src.layout,
          dest: settings.theme.roots.dist,
        },
        {
          src: settings.theme.src.locales,
          dest: settings.theme.roots.dist,
        },
        {
          src: settings.theme.src.snippets,
          dest: settings.theme.roots.dist,
        },
        {
          src: settings.theme.src.sections,
          dest: settings.theme.roots.dist,
        },
        {
          src: settings.theme.src.templates,
          dest: settings.theme.roots.dist,
        },
        {
          src: settings.theme.src.config,
          dest: settings.theme.roots.dist,
        },
      ])),
    createHtmlPlugin({
      filename: path.resolve(settings.theme.dist.snippets, 'script-tags.liquid'),
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib', 'script-tags.html'),
      inject: {
        data: {
          liquidTemplates: getTemplateEntrypoints(settings),
          liquidLayouts: getLayoutEntrypoints(settings),
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    outDir: settings.theme.dist.assets,
    assetsDir: settings.theme.src.assets,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        ...getLayoutEntrypoints(settings),
        ...getTemplateEntrypoints(settings),
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: '[name].bundle.[hash:6].js',
        chunkFileNames: '[name].bundle.[hash:6].js',
        assetFileNames: '[name].[ext]',
      },
    },
  },
};

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode, ssr }) => {
  if (mode === 'dev') {
    console.log('in dev');
    return baseConfig;
  }

  console.log('out of dev');
  console.log(command);
  return baseConfig;
});
```

As of now, when I allow vite to build, it successfully bundles the js files, and the vite-plugin-copy works, but no script-tags.liquid file is created. I get no errors either.

I tried having it output an html file instead which did nothing, and I tried running the build with the --debug flag but nothing relevant came out of it

What I would expect is that a script-tags.liquid gets created in dist/snippets directory.
Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a similar transition in my project from Webpack to Vite. We were using HtmlWebpackPlugin with .ejs templates in the project and also tried to solve the transition with the same plugin as you did but never got it working correctly. I don't remember what was the original problem we faced when using that particular plugin but I eventually ended up writing my own simple plugin for the requirements we had: https://github.com/gedouu/vite-plugin-generate-html

I hope this helps if someone is facing similar problems.